# SQL Server decimal variable assignment?

Tags: sql, t-sql, types, casting, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a stored procedure and I'm getting unexpected divide by 0 exceptions.

I've narrowed it down to the following example.

Why in the world does this :

```
    declare @A decimal;
    declare @B decimal;
    declare @C decimal;

    set @A = 4;
    set @B = 9;
    set @C = @A/@B 

    select @A/@B as 'Expected'
    select @C as 'Wut'
```

result in this?

```
    Expected
    ---------------------------------------
    0.4444444444444444444

    (1 row(s) affected)

    Wut
    ---------------------------------------
    0

    (1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't specified a scale for the `decimal` type. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx):

> *s (scale)*
>
> > The number of decimal digits that will be stored to the right of the decimal point. This number is substracted from p to determine the maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through p. Scale can be specified only if precision is specified. **The default scale is 0**; therefore, 0 <= s <= p.

So when you try to store `@A/@B` back into `@C`, the fractional part gets truncated.

Notice:

```
declare @A decimal(18, 3);
declare @B decimal(18, 3);
declare @C decimal(18, 3);

set @A = 4;
set @B = 9;
set @C = @A/@B 

select @A/@B -- 0.44444444444444444444
select @C    -- 0.444
```

Comment: I can see the OP's confusion, though, since dividing two decimals without scale *does* shows decimal places

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because if you don't declare precision and scale, a Decimal defualts to `(18, 0)` 18 digits to the left of the decimal point, and 0 to the right.

If you change C to be defined like this:

```
declare @A decimal;
declare @B decimal;
declare @C decimal (18, 9);

set @A = 4;
set @B = 9;
set @C = @A/@B 

select @A/@B as 'Expected'
select @C as 'Wut'
```

You should get a proper answer

```
Expected
---------------------------------------
0.4444444444444444444

(1 row(s) affected)

Wut
---------------------------------------
0.444444444

(1 row(s) affected)
```