# Putting variables into equation rounds their values

Tags: sql, sql-server, expression, decimal

I have 2 `DECIMAL(17,5)` variables which are producing accurate calculations.  When they hit expressions they keep rounding their values.

Using the watch list I have deduced this much:

```
@TotalAmount = 62.30000
@ConversionValue = 0.74630
```

HOWEVER

```
SELECT @TotalAmount * @ConversionValue
```

is returning 62 when it should be returning 46.49449

```
CAST(@TotalAmount AS decimal(17,5)) returns 62.00000
CAST(@ConversionValue AS decimal(17,5)) returns 1.00000

SELECT @TotalAmount returns 62.00000
SELECT @ConversionValue returns 1.00000
```

Comment: what are these variables declared as?

Comment: Look at my post here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455547/sql-server-decimal30-10-losing-last-2-decimals/1455665#1455665

Comment: You haven't actually shown us your code which declares those variables, and that appears to be where the issues lies.

Comment: the variables were declared as DECIMAL(18, 5)…
the code really didn't matter, just the variables and the watch window...

Comment: I actually figured it out (kind of) the problem is the debugger for ssms was not showing the correct values (it was actually rounding the values ONLY in the watch window)

Comment: Now to figure out why the watch list is rounding all the variables off

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're on SQL Server rather than postgres or mySQL here you used the SSMS tag).

If this is the case I'd just be explicit and 'overly' precise in your variable declaration. Also take note you can get 'more' precision in memory that will be truncated if the original variable isn't correct. A similar post here:

[SQL Server decimal variable assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016501/sql-server-decimal-variable-assignment)

```
declare @A decimal(18, 3);
declare @B decimal(18, 3);
declare @C decimal(18, 3);

set @A = 4;
set @B = 9;
set @C = @A/@B 

select @A/@B -- 0.44444444444444444444
select @C    -- 0.444
```